# Avoid long deployment scanner delay for static content WAR

Tags: wildfly

I'm running Wildfly 10, and among many other things my product contains a StaticContent.war, with exactly that - static content (HTML, JS, CSS, images, ...). The size of the WAR is considerable (1700 files, 150MB), and so the deployment scanner (I presume) spends quite some time (10 sec) to scan the file.

Is whatever happens here necessary? Is there a way to avoid this delay?

Comment: Do you really want to deploy static war file on wildfly ? Can you deploy it on webserver(Apach) which is configured infront of wildfly instance as loadbalancer ?

Comment: If it's a WAR there's not much you can do. If it's not required to be a WAR you could just create an Undertow file handler to access the content.

Comment: You can deploy it via admin console / cli in which case it won't be affected by deployment scanner

Comment: Yes, I want this as a war file - our deployment is sufficiently complex as it is, adding loadbalancer and another server is not an option.
I've investigated the Undertow file handler approach, but I would like to have the static content in a single archive, and Undertow unfortunately does not seem to support that (a ZIP file, for instance)
Deploying via admin console/cli doesn't work - the file is just part of a deployment of our application, and the idea here is to reduce the start-up time.